# Angular 2: How to make directive do something only once component is initialized?

Tags: angular

I am trying to make it so that the directive does something right when the component is initialized, but I have async issues.

I have this is in my directive:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._myCentralSvc.sendMessage('receiveUpdates', runMeOnUpdates)
}

runMeOnUpdates(): void {
 // function code to alter component's state via Renderer and nativeElement  
}
```

The directive is an attribute of an HTML element, in the component's template and it needs to change the HTML element when the component is initialized.

Comment: Please provide more details. I don't see anything async and I don't see anything that could cause issues.

Comment: I looked it over again. I assume "sendMessage" is an async call of some kind triggered through your myCentralSvc. So sooner or later that runMeOnUpdates will return. In the meantime, you have a component left hanging for some piece of data that you need. Couldn't you just use a default value for that piece of data until that call returns?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 usage of this directive and want to send just one message for them all? Then static variables is the answer.

Comment: Tim Consolazio, your understanding is correct. Just to clarify, sendMessage is not a call to external resources (like http), more like grabbing a value that exists elsewhere in the application state. But I believe it is still an async issue, since the component is left hanging? The component also has its own ngOnInit/ngAfterViewInit state.

Comment: Daniel Kucal, the component is for a video, and there are multiple videos in the application. I have also considered the usage of global variables - is that what you mean by static variables?